# Post-Aggregation Join of two tables in Tableau

Tags: tableau-api

I´m new to tableau and need to do some kind of post-aggregation join, i think. My goal is, to match some data from google search console to some other regional data concerning hotels. This way, i hope to see if hotels for a certain region perform better or worse than their popularity in the google searches would suggest.

I have one table with the hotel-data which looks like this:

**Table 1**

[image]

Here we have three hierarchical region levels. Country, state and region (and some KPI that is aggregated according to the drill-down-level).

**Table 2**

[image]

Table 2 does not follow the hierarchical dimensionality as table 1, but has the same regions.

**What i want tableau to do:**

I want tableau, to join the regions on the lowest region level, but NOT to aggregate the KPI impressions. So, when i drill-up to the country level, i want the "random KPI" to be summed to 389, but the impressions should be 40.000 only. You might ask yourself why - it´s a different thing if somebody only searches for "country 1" or if he searches for a state or region of this country. For this analysis it is the goal, to not aggregate the impressions for each region.

[image]

I would be glad for any hints on how to do this. I thought about doing a blend - which i thought is a kind of post-aggregation join, but i found out, that if i join on the lowest region-level of table 1 with the region-variable of table 2, the impressions always get aggregated.
Thanks everyone!

Comment: what if you blend, but make the impressions a dimension, so it doesn't aggregate?

Comment: Hey Andy, thanks for responding to my question! I´ve got the feeling, that it´s the drill-down that automatically does an aggregation on the upper regional level. Perhaps i need to do a workaround where i give users a parameter to choose the drill-down level and have 3 different tables (according to the drill-down-level) where i blend in the second table with the impressions.

Comment: perhaps aggregate as a MIN. This effectively should act like a constant as well.

Comment: Ah, good idea! Thanks, i´ll try it out!